# Grunt.js spawns a new node process when using the watch task

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs

Grunt.js is obviously spawning a new node.js process when using grunt's watch task:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgRlcFt9dkg

As soon as I save my document the default task is executed and (as you can see in the video) there suddenly is a new node.exe process.

This is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-yui-compressor');

  // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Metadata.
        meta: {
            version: '1.0',
        },
        banner: '/*! Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> */\n',
        // Task configuration.
        concat: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>',
                stripBanners: true
            },
            develop: {
                src: ['js/app.main.js', 'js/app/*.js', 'js/app.debug.js', 'js/app.workarounds.js', 'js/app.init.js'],
                dest: 'build/js/app.js'
            },
            production: {
                src: ['js/app.main.js', 'js/app/*.js', 'js/app.workarounds.js', 'js/app.init.js'],
                dest: 'build/js/app.js'
            },
            habla_css: {
                src: ['build/habla.css'],
                dest: 'build/habla.css'
            },
            wiwo_css: {
                src: ['build/wiwo.css'],
                dest: 'build/wiwo.css'
            },
            iefix: {
                src: 'js/iefix/*',
                dest: 'build/js/iefix.js'
            },
            libs: {
                src: ['js/src/*'],
                dest: 'build/js/libs.js'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            pre: [
                'build'
            ],
            post: 'dest'
        },
        copy: {
            thirdparty: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true, 
                        src: ['js/jquery.min.js'],
                        dest: 'build/',
                    }]
            }
        },
        min: {
            options: {
                report: false,
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
            },
            app: {
                src: ['build/js/app.js'],
                dest: 'build/js/app.min.js'
            },
            iefix: {
                src: 'js/iefix.js',
                dest: 'build/js/iefix.min.js'
            },
            libs: {
                src: ['js/src/*'],
                dest: 'build/js/libs.min.js'
            },
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                report: false,
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
            },
            icons: {
                src: ['build/icons.css'],
                dest: 'build/icons.min.css'
            },
            habla: {
                src: ['build/habla.css'],
                dest: 'build/habla.min.css'
            },
            wiwo: {
                src: ['build/wiwo.css'],
                dest: 'build/wiwo.min.css'
            }
        },
        less: {
            icons: {
                src: ['less/system/icons.less'],
                dest: 'build/icons.css'
            },
            habla: {
                src: ['less/habla.less'],
                dest: 'build/habla.css'
            },
            wiwo: {
                src: ['less/wiwo.less'],
                dest: 'build/wiwo.css'
            }
        },
        replace: {
            production: {
                src: 'build/js/app.js',
                dest: 'build/js/app.js',
                replacements: [{
                    from: /\s*App.debug.(log|group|groupEnd)\(.*\);/g,
                    to: ''
                },
                {
                    from: 'debug: true',
                    to: 'debug: false'
                }]
            },
            date: {
                src: 'build/js/app.js',
                dest: 'build/js/app.js',
                replacements: [{
                    from: '/*!%CURDATE%*/',
                    to: 'console.log("' + d.replace(/(T|Z)/gi,' ') + '");'
                }]
            }
        },
        qunit: {
            files: ['tests/**/*.html']
        },
        watch: {
            main: {
                files: ['grunt.js', 'js/app.*.js', 'js/**/*', 'less/**/*', 'less/*'],
                tasks: ['default'],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true
                }
            }
        }

    });


    grunt.registerTask('con', ['concat:habla_css', 'concat:wiwo_css', 'concat:iefix', 'concat:libs']);
    grunt.registerTask('icons', ['less:icons cssmin:icons']);
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['qunit']);

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:habla', 'less:wiwo', 'concat:develop', 'con', 'replace:date', 'copy:thirdparty', 'clean:post', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('release', ['clean:pre', 'less', 'concat:production', 'con', 'replace:production', 'copy:thirdparty', 'min', 'cssmin', 'clean:post']);

};
```

So is it a grunt bug or a bug in my gruntfile? The grunt version I'm using is 0.4.1 (+ grunt-cli 0.1.9) on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Could be one of your tasks that's spawning a new Node process (perhaps the Less task?).

Answer (score 5):

You should not have `'watch'` as the final task in your default task sequence. Your watch configuration invokes default, which then spawns another watch task each time. This line is the problem:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:habla', 'less:wiwo', 'concat:develop', 'con', 'replace:date', 'copy:thirdparty', 'clean:post', 'watch']);
```

It should be this instead:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:habla', 'less:wiwo', 'concat:develop', 'con', 'replace:date', 'copy:thirdparty', 'clean:post']);
```

You should simply run `grunt:watch` in order to watch the files.

And if you want to run the default task sequence without doing watch, then you can simply run `grunt`

Answer (score 1):

That's it. Thank you!

I optimized it a little bit so I can still run `grunt` (without to specify the `watch` parameter):

```
watch: {
    main: {
        files: ['grunt.js', 'js/app.*.js', 'js/**/*', 'less/**/*', 'less/*'],
        tasks: ['develop']
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('develop', ['less:habla', 'less:wiwo', 'concat:develop', 'con', 'replace:date', 'copy:thirdparty', 'clean:post']);
grunt.registerTask('release', ['clean:pre', 'less', 'concat:production', 'con', 'replace:production', 'copy:thirdparty', 'min', 'cssmin', 'clean:post']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['develop', 'watch']);
```

Works fine! Thanks!